# How to get Single Id from Multiple ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I close to my result but i got array of ids and now i send one at a time when my cursor in input box.
i got array of id i show on console 
check out

[image]

How i get only one 'iD'.You saw in image there lots of thing but i want only one id in which my cursor focus.

```
$(function(){
        var $write = $( "input[type=text]" ).focus(function() {
        shift = false,
        capslock = false;
        backspace  = false;
        console.log(Object.values($write));
            $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    character = $this.html(); 

                // Shift keys
                if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
                    $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                    $('.symbol span').toggle();

                    shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
                    capslock = false;
                    backspace  = false;
                    return false;
                }

                // Caps lock
                if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
                    $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                    capslock = true;
                    return false;
                }

                // backspace lock
                if ($this.hasClass('backspace')) {
                    $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                    capslock = true;
                    return false;
                }

                // Delete
                    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
                        var html = $write.html(),
                        txt = html.substr(0, html.length - 1);
                      $write.html(txt);
                      $write.autocomplete("search", txt);
                      return false;
                    }
                    // Delete

                // Special characters
                if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
                if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
                if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
                if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

                // Uppercase letter
                if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

                // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
                if (shift === true) {
                    $('.symbol span').toggle();
                    if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

                    shift = false;
                }
                //console.log("DO IT ", character);
                // Add the character
                $write.val($write.val() + character);       
                $write.html(txt);
                $write.autocomplete("search", txt);


            }); 
        });
        });
```

Comment: "ID" should not be multiple.It should be unique

Comment: ya your are right different input box shoul have different id

Comment: so i want only when i focus in one input box so its give me input box Id only like first input box Id is "ItemNo_1" and second input box id is ItemNo_2 so when i focus on first it should itemNo_1

Comment: have any suggestion  @Krishna Prashatt

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing but I will give it a shot:

1. It prints a lot of stuff because you are doing `console.log(Object.values($write));`, you are printing all of the values the selected object has, not just the id.

The syntax to just print the id of an object is: `console.log($myObject.attr('id'));`

2. If you are trying to use a property that many elements share (not unique), use Class instead of Id. You will get an array of objects and you can parse through them or get them by index.